# Debezium is not working with redis streams and postgresql

Tags: postgresql, debezium, redis-streams

I'm having an issue with running debezium with redis and postgresql.

My docker compose is:

```yaml
version: "3.3"
services:
  redis-stack:
    image: redis/redis-stack:7.0.6-RC4
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 10001:6379
      - 13333:8001
    volumes:
      - ./data/redis-stack/:/data

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 1234

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 5555:80
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: 1234
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: arkan.m.gerges@gmail.com

  debezium:
    image: debezium/server:2.1.2.Final
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8180:8080
    volumes:
      - ./config/debezium:/debezium/conf
      - ./data/debezium:/debezium/data
    depends_on:
      - redis-stack
      - db

networks:
    app-network:
```

in the config/debezium/application.properties

```ini
debezium.source.connector.class=io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector
debezium.source.offset.storage=io.debezium.storage.redis.offset.RedisOffsetBackingStore
debezium.source.offset.flush.interval.ms=0
debezium.source.offset.storage.redis.address=redis-stack:6379
debezium.source.schema.history.internal=io.debezium.storage.redis.history.RedisSchemaHistory
debezium.source.schema.history.internal.redis.address=redis-stack:6379
debezium.sink.type=redis
debezium.sink.redis.address=redis-stack:6379
debezium.source.database.hostname=db
debezium.source.database.port=5432
debezium.source.database.user=postgres
debezium.source.database.password=1234
debezium.source.database.dbname=softwaredev_expert
debezium.source.database.server.name=db
debezium.source.schema.whitelist=public
debezium.source.schema.include.list=public
debezium.source.plugin.name=pgoutput
```

I can access redis insights, and access to postgresql, but I'm getting errors running debezium:

https://pastebin.com/9TGUNvKe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the issue with the following application.properties
Here I've used the outbox pattern and for each aggregate type, a new stream will be created, but all the events for that aggregate will be in the same stream.

```ini
# Debezium redis sink connector
debezium.sink.type=redis
debezium.sink.redis.address=redis-stack:6379
debezium.source.connector.class=io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector
debezium.source.offset.storage=io.debezium.storage.redis.offset.RedisOffsetBackingStore
debezium.source.offset.flush.interval.ms=0
debezium.source.offset.storage.redis.address=redis-stack:6379
debezium.source.schema.history.internal=io.debezium.storage.redis.history.RedisSchemaHistory
debezium.source.schema.history.internal.redis.address=redis-stack:6379

# Source database connection info
debezium.source.database.hostname=db
debezium.source.database.port=5432
debezium.source.database.user=postgres
debezium.source.database.password=1234
debezium.source.database.dbname=softwaredev_expert
debezium.source.table.include.list=public.outbox_events
debezium.source.plugin.name=pgoutput
debezium.source.topic.prefix=swdevexpert

# Outbox event router
debezium.transforms=outbox
debezium.transforms.outbox.type=io.debezium.transforms.outbox.EventRouter
debezium.transforms.outbox.route.topic.replacement=swdevexpert.events.$1
```

I filtered only the database table `outbox_events`

And my docker-compose is:

```yaml
version: "3.3"
services:
  redis-stack:
    image: redis/redis-stack:7.0.6-RC4
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "10001:6379"
      - "13333:8001"
    volumes:
      - ./data/redis-stack/:/data

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 1234
    command:
      - "-c"
      - "config_file=/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf"
    volumes:
      - ./data/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./config/postgresql/postgresql.conf:/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "5555:80"
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: 1234
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: arkan.m.gerges@gmail.com

  debezium:
    image: debezium/server:2.1.2.Final
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./config/debezium:/debezium/conf
      - ./data/debezium:/debezium/data
    depends_on:
      - redis-stack
      - db

networks:
    app-network:
```

And in config/postgresql/postgresql.conf

```ini
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
max_connections = 20
shared_buffers = 128MB
temp_buffers = 8MB
work_mem = 4MB
wal_level = logical
max_wal_senders = 3
max_replication_slots = 100
```

Some of the sql inserts, I did not put it in one line to experiment with different timestamp:

```sql
    insert into outbox_events (id, aggregatetype, aggregateid, type, payload)
      values (uuid_generate_v4(), 'order', '111', 'my_type', '{"order_id": "111", "order_type": "car"}');
      
    insert into outbox_events (id, aggregatetype, aggregateid, type, payload)
      values (uuid_generate_v4(), 'order2', '222', 'my_type', '{"order_id": "222", "order_type": "house"}');
      
    insert into outbox_events (id, aggregatetype, aggregateid, type, payload)
      values (uuid_generate_v4(), 'order1234567890', '333', 'my_type', '{"order_id": "333", "order_type": "computer"}');
      
    insert into outbox_events (id, aggregatetype, aggregateid, type, payload)
      values (uuid_generate_v4(), 'order1234567890', '444', 'my_type', '{"order_id": "444", "order_type": "computer"}');
      
    insert into outbox_events (id, aggregatetype, aggregateid, type, payload)
      values (uuid_generate_v4(), 'order1234567890_one_two', '555', 'my_type', '{"order_id": "555", "order_type": "computer"}');
```

And on redis insight:

[image]